# Share не обрабатывается в toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, toolbar

Добрый день! Подключил `Toolbar`. В нём создал две кнопки: search и share.
Обработку последней делаю через `ShareActionProvider`. Однако при тестировании, кнопка share не реагирует на нажатия. При дебаге, видно, что код весь отрабатывает нормально, `null` нигде не получается. Код ниже:
Разметка `Toolbar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Разметка `layout` где подключается `Toolbar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view_photo_hamster"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_like_hamster"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Разметка меню:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/search"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:orderInCategory="20"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/share"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

`Activity` где я подключил `Toolbar`:

```
    import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import ru.aleksandrorlov.crazyhamster.data.Contract;

public class ViewHamsterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_hamster);
        initToolbar();
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        try {
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
        ShareActionProvider sap = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);

        Intent intentTxt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intentTxt.setType("text/plain");
        intentTxt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "e-mail");

        sap.setShareIntent(intentTxt);

        Intent intentImg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intentTxt.setType("image/*");
        intentTxt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "imageUri");

        sap.setShareIntent(intentImg);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.menu_item_search:
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Для выделения `вот так` используйте вместо апострофа знак ` это такой апостроф кривой

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.menu_item_search:
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
       case R.id.menu_item_share:
            ShareActionProvider sap = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
            Intent intentTxt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            //сюда логику перенесите
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Я, конечно, давно под андроид не писал, но почему вы клик реализовали в onCreateOptionsMenu, а не там где это положено? Попробуйте вот так

**Update**

1) Вот [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html) написано, что надо у атрибута `android:actionProviderClass`
выставить значение `android.widget.ShareActionProvider`. Попробуйте, мб поможет.

2) Зачем тут имплементирован интерфейс `onClickListener`?

3) Вы уверены что два раза подряд `sap.setShareIntent` корректно отработают?

Comment: Сейчас на память не вспомню где я нагуглил. Но читал, что ни в коем случае не реализовывать это в onClick

Comment: Реализовал Ваш вариант - не работает. Видел другие варианты реализации, без ShareActionProvider, запуск происходит через starActivity()

Comment: обновил ответ, проверьте

Comment: 1. Это уже было проделано, до того как я задал здесь свой вопрос.
2. Обрабатывается нажатие кнопок search и назад.

Comment: 3. попробовал 1 оставить. Изменений нет. Нажатие не отрабатывается.

Answer (score 0):

В общем вот так заработал:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu");
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    provider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    provider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

    return true;
}

private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "imageUri");
    return shareIntent;
}
```